# How to pass a string that read from keyboard to functions such as isdecimal?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am using Python 2.7.4 here, and I know how to define a string as Unicode, by

```
a = u"abcd"
```

I tried reading a string from keyboard using **`raw_input()`**, and I want  pass the string that I read to ***isX()*** function such as **`isdecimal()`**, **`isalnum()`** etc. But when I do that, I gets error message like this.

> │AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isdecimal'

Is there anyway that I can use, so that I can read string, and pass these strings to these functions such as isdecimal?

I can explain an example case to you.

```
a = raw_input()
```

I inputs **'two'** to the variable **a**. And then,

```
print(a.isdecimal())
```

I want to print **`False`** instead of printing the given error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really wanna know how to do, given the way you wrote your question is:
How to convert raw_input()'s output to a unicode object so that you can use .isdecimal() because that is a Unicode object only function.

To answer that question, you can do the below to automatically do that conversion when getting the input:

```
text= raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding or locale.getpreferredencoding(True))
```

The whole code would look like this:

```
import sys, locale
text= raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding or locale.getpreferredencoding(True))
print(text.isdecimal())
```

By the way, you have .isdigit() for non Unicode (aka normal strings).
To avoid all this hassle with string to Unicode conversion I'd advise you to move to python 3 if you have no strong need to stay with 2.7.*

Answer (score -1):

Yes for example i tried below:-

```
a = 0
try:
    a = int(raw_input())
    print isX(a)
except:
  print "Wrong Input"
```

In this case if you pass a string then also it works normally.

Comment: This only checks if the function exists.
isnumerical, isdecimal are functions of the unicode object.
isdigit is a property of both unicode and str.

Your code doesn't work, first because those functions are either in the object or class, you can't just call them as builtin. Second, as you're converting the input to a int and the type int doesn't have the mentioned functions.

Comment: @DallaRosa, ok Thanks

Comment: If you fix your answer (try running your code in some inputs) I'm happy to remove the -1 :)